# Is there any possibility to insert HTML tag into the file which is reside on server through selenium automation?

Tags: python, selenium

I have created simple automation which will first read the read subdomain folder and then it will get into it and then find for the specific html file. If it will find it (i.e: .html) then edit it and i want to add the specific tag somewhere in that file but i am unable to do it.

```
staticWord = "Hair"
    htmlTag = "<a href='"+ staticRandomPathList[0] + "'>" + staticWord + "</a>"
    print(htmlTag)
    # Now on we are working statically
    folderfound = 0
    filefound = 0
    for domainNameFolder in range(len(staticRandomPathList)):
        subDomainSelectedFilesAddress = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//table/tbody/tr[" + str(domainNameFolder + 1) + "]/td[" + str(1) + "]")
        subDomainName = new_list[domainNameFolder] + '.' + domain_list[domain_variable]
        if subDomainSelectedFilesAddress.text == "logs" or subDomainSelectedFilesAddress.text == "public_html":
            continue
        else:
            if subDomainSelectedFilesAddress.text == "test1.testlab.com":
                action = ActionChains(driver)
                action.double_click(subDomainSelectedFilesAddress).perform()
                time.sleep(1)
                for file in range(0, 10):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    selectedFile = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[" + str(
                        file + 1) + "]/td[" + str(1) + "]")
                    if selectedFile.text == "5.html":
                        selectedFile.click()
                        editFile = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@ng-click='showHTMLEditorModal()']")
                        editFile.click()


                        # addHtmlTag = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                        #     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ace_content")))
                        # insertAnchorTag = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ace_content")
                        # insertAnchorTag.click()
                        #
                        time.sleep(2)
                        textinput = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ace_text-layer")
                        print(textinput.text)

                        gettingTextFromServer = textinput.text

                        Html_file = open("HTMLParsing.html", "w")
                        newHTMLFile = Html_file.write(gettingTextFromServer)
                        html = newHTMLFile
                        print(html)
                        # soup = Soup(html)
                        # bodyTag = soup.find('body')
                        # anchor = soup.new_tag('a')
                        # anchor['href'] = staticRandomPathList[0]
                        # bodyTag.insert(anchor)


                        Html_file.close()



                        # print(insertAnchorTag.text)



                        # mapHTMLTag =  driver.find_element(By.ID, "id='htmlEditorContent'")
                        # mapHTMLTag.send_keys(htmlTag)


                        # addHtmlTag.send_keys(htmlTag)
                        filefound = 1
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                if filefound == 1:
                    break
                folderfound = 1
                break
            else:
                continue

    print("Successfully Outside Loop")
```

I am attaching the picture so you would be able to see where I want to place that tag.

[image]

Comment: A server you have access to or someone else's? The latter obviously wouldn't be possible, as any mechanism selenium uses could also be used to hack the server, unless there is a specific secure API that server provides for the purpose.

Comment: The server is mine. I have all the access of the required sever.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything selenium specific to do that, so the question is really how to change content of a live web page in the web server, which depends on the server and framework in use and probably has an answer here already. You can then either use selenium to trigger the change through the UI or make a HTTP request direct from Python if it's not exposed as UI (I use that for a 'reset the UI Test project' API that is called before selenium tests so they all start from a known state)

Answer (score 0):

This is nodejs selenium code that works. May be you can reproduce in python. Don't forget to navigate to any page page before editing page html. Good luck.

```
  async navigateToHomePage() {
        logger.info(`inside navigateToHomePage`)
        await driver.get(this.baseUrl)
    }

  async insertHtmlIntoDocumentBody(html) {
        logger.info(`inside insertHtmlIntoDocumentBody`)

        let htmlElement = driver.findElement(By.css('html'))
        let headElement = driver.findElement(By.css('head'))
        let bodyElement = driver.findElement(By.css('body'))

        logger.info(`starting html edition`)

        await driver.executeScript(`let div = 
        document.createElement('html'); 
        div.innerHTML='${JSON.stringify(html)}'; 
        arguments[0].removeChild(arguments[1]); 
        arguments[0].removeChild(arguments[2]); 
        arguments[0].appendChild(div)`, htmlElement, headElement, 
        bodyElement)

        logger.info(`completed html edition`)
    }
```